# set a rails controller's response type to xml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, respond-to, respond-with

i'm quite new to rails. i'm trying to set a rails controller's response type to xml, but not having much luck. i could certainly afford to better understand how respond_to and respond_with work.

here's what my controller looks like:

```
class ResponsesController < ApplicationController

 respond_to :xml

  def index

    require 'rubygems'   
    require 'telapi'

        ix = Telapi::InboundXml.new do

          Say('Hello.', :loop => 3, :voice => 'man')
          Say('Hello, my name is Jane.', :voice => 'woman')
          Say('Now I will not stop talking.', :loop => 0)
        end

        respond_with do |format|
            format.xml { render }
        end

        puts ix.response 

    end
end
```

this leads to an http retrieval failure. can someone advise me how to how i can fix the controller and set its response type to xml? also, a cogent 1-2 liner of how respond_to and respond_with work would be awesome!

thanks everyone.

Comment: try format.xml { render xml: ix }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace

```
  respond_with do |format|
            format.xml { render }
        end
```

with

```
respond_with(ix)
```

There are 2 ways of rendering a xml. Example 1 uses respond_to that means "every single method will use xml and use the object parse in from respond_with"

Example 2 uses respond_to that means "use the block below to declare what type of respond and the object to be parse"

example 1:

```
class ResponsesController
  respond_to :xml #respond_to A

  def index
    respond_with(@asd) # respond_with A
  end
end
```

example 2:

```
def ResponsesController

  def index
    respond_to do |format|
     format.xml { render xml: @asd}
    end
  end
end
```

http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2009/08/embracing-rest-with-mind-body-and-soul/

Comment: Thanks for your help. I ended up using something similar i.e. format.xml { render :xml => xml.response }